# require a blank line between fields if annotations are on separate lines?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

Basically I want different styles depending on annotation count, e.g.

```
class Foo {
  @Autowire private MyService myService;
  @Autowire private MyOtherService service;

  ...
 }
```

but if I have more annotations require a space

```
@Entity
class Bar {
  @Id
  @NotNull
  @Column(...)
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  @Column(...)
  private String description;
}
```

can I coerce IDEA into formatting Java for these 2 styles?

Answer (score -2):

Under Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces, specify field annotations to "Wrap Always" and tick the "Do not wrap after single annotation" box.

Graphic:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that fixes my problem of forcing a newline if multiple annotations.

Comment: That's something related specific to a field, actually, but it changes it unconditionally.